# delete rows of dataframe where 3 values are A

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Data-Sample:

```
id   col1 col2 col3 col4
1    100   100   100    a
2    200   100   100    b
3    100   300   100    c
```

should become:

```
id   col1 col2 col3 col4
2    200   100   100    b
3    100   300   100    c
```

tried to use

```
df = df[(df['col1'] != 100) & (df['col2'] != 100)]
```

but this removed almost all of the rows instead of the ones with all same value in it

**difficult part is that there are also other columns which shuld not be affected**

Comment: are you looking for particular columns  or on the entire  dataFrame ?  if on the entire dataFrame then you can try `~df[(df > 100).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: particular columns and a specific value of 100 not bigger than =)

Comment: Oh then your expected output is not correct.

Comment: why is that? it could be a bit clearer i guess but two downvotes? thank you very much for a question with a suitable answer

Comment: i  did not downvoted.. i never do that at all.

Comment: sorry should have wrote that in another comment ;) was not about you but the two other nice people. i tried to clarify my outcome. do you think it fits now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `nunique`

```
df[df[['col1','col2','col3']].nunique(1)>1]
```

Then

```
~df[['col1','col2','col3']].eq(100).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: issue here is that there are also other values in the rows like object_nr

Comment: actually i forgott something else, its about if they have a specific value lets say 100 if col1,2 and 3 have 100 then this row should be removed

Comment: i'm on it. trying to implement that and test it, thank you so much so far =)

Comment: tryed to use df = df.drop(yourcommand) but this gives mey a keyarror not found

Comment: @J.Doe do it just  df=df[['col1','col2','col3']].eq(100).all(axis=1)

Comment: did try that, gives me keyerror because of the number column at the end

Comment: after a few try and error runs with your code i got it working. i felt free to ad something to your solution. thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:**

```
  df=df[~df[['a','b','c']].eq('A').all(axis=1)]
```

> Output:

```
print(df)
```

---

```
   a  b  c    d
2  A  A  B  445
3  A  B  C  332
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion i had with Joe..

1. We have a DataFrame which have four columns and initial three column values are all ints whereas fourth column has strings values.
2. Now, here we are looking for if in column `col1  col2  col3` any row that contains `100` that row needs to be removed.
3. Now, if we look at the data-Frame Structure and in this case then it's pretty easy to catch and get the desired outcome as we see `col4` having a value `a` in the first row so, we can catch it from there. But catch it here if we all the row values are `100` but the last value is not `a` with a large DataFame then this approach will not suffice to get the results.

### DataFrame Example:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3 col4
0   100   100   100    a
1   200   100   100    b
2   100   300   100    c
```

### What could be Solution(s):

Solution 1:

```
>>> df[df.col4 != 'a']
   col1  col2  col3 col4
1   200   100   100    b
2   100   300   100    c
```

Solution 2:

```
>>> df.loc[lambda df: df.col4 != 'a']
   col1  col2  col3 col4
1   200   100   100    b
2   100   300   100    c
```

But as i mentioned above will only work if we know that `col4` having value `a` in it hence we need to have another tactical approach to handle this, which we see one of the @WeNYoBen answer.

### However i'll illustrate some other approach of achieving the same here..

We will use Index approach  `.ix` is the most general indexer and will support any of the inputs in `.loc` and `.iloc`. `.ix` also supports floating point label schemes. `.ix` is exceptionally useful when dealing with mixed positional and label based hierarchical indexes.

Solution 3:

```
>>> df.ix[(df['col1'] != 100) | (df['col2'] != 100) | (df['col3'] != 100)]
   col1  col2  col3 col4
1   200   100   100    b
2   100   300   100    c
```

Solution 4:

We will use `query()` method which also supports special use of Python’s in and not in comparison operators, providing a succinct syntax for calling the isin method of a Series or DataFrame.

```
>>> df.query('col1 != col2 and col3 != col4')
# df.query('col1 != col2 & col3 != col4')

   col1  col2  col3 col4
1   200   100   100    b
2   100   300   100    c
```

@another question he has, can we delete columns with all values of 100 in every row of the column?

Solution:

Yes we can do that, let's take an example dataFrame similar to previous with additional rows the for removing row having the same values across columns can be transposed, *When the dtype is homogeneous in the original DataFrame, we get a transposed DataFrame with the same dtype:*

### DataFrame Example:

```
>>> df
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  100  100  100    a
1  200  100  100    b
2  100  300  100    c
3  100  100  100  100
4  100  100  100  100
```

As we see in the above DataFrame the last two rows have a same values which we can drop.

Lets see how transpose looks like for the DataFrame, we see below all the rows became columns and  column's became Index, now it clearly show the last two column `3 & 4` on the transposed DataFrame having the same values which we can delete/drop/remove or mask.

```
>>> df.T
        0    1    2    3    4
col1  100  200  100  100  100
col2  100  100  300  100  100
col3  100  100  100  100  100
col4    a    b    c  100  100
```

Now try ..

```
>>> df[(df.T != 100).any()]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  100  100  100    a
1  200  100  100    b
2  100  300  100    c
```

We are using `DataFrame.any()` as it *Return whether any element is True, potentially over an axis.*